# Zebra_datepicker add class to clicked date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

My situation: 
I'm using the zebra_datepicker for a booking process. 
I've 2 datepickers which are paired (so the 2nd one is 1 day later dann the 1st).
- these dates (and the dates between) will be saved inside of an array
- I initialize the datepickers again and set the disabled_dates to my array (so the booked dates are disabled)

Now, my question:
I'm trying to add a class to the first selected date (first datepicker) and the last selected date (second datepicker) after button click. Anyone there who could help?
Thanks!

Update (some code examples):

HTML:

```
<div class="flatArrive">
    <div class="Zebra_DatePicker_Icon_Wrapper">
        <input id="inputArrive"/>
        <div id="calendarArrive"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flatDepart">
    <div class="Zebra_DatePicker_Icon_Wrapper">
        <input id="inputDepart"/>
        <div id="calendarDepart"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="submitBooking" value="reservate!"/>
```

Init the datepickers:

```
var disabledDates = [];
$('#inputArrive').Zebra_DatePicker({
            disabled_dates: disabledDates,
            direction: 1,
            pair: $('#inputDepart')
});

$('#inputDepart').Zebra_DatePicker({
            disabled_dates: disabledDates,
            direction: 1
});
```

function to get disabled (booked) dates:

```
getDatesBetweenArriveAndDepart : function (arrive, depart) {
        var arriveTS = parseInt(moment(arrive.val(), 'DD.MM.YYYY').format('X'), 10),
            departTS = parseInt(moment(depart.val(), 'DD.MM.YYYY').format('X'), 10),
            daysToReservate = [];

        while (arriveTS <= departTS) {
            if($.inArray(moment.unix(arriveTS).format('DD MM YYYY'), this.disabledDates) === -1) {
                daysToReservate.push(moment.unix(arriveTS).format('DD MM YYYY'));
                arriveTS += this.dayInMs;
            } else {
                alert('You cant book twice');
                daysToReservate = [];
                return;
            }
        }

        $.merge(disabledDates, daysToReservate);
    }
```

Call my function on button click and init calendars again with filled disabledDates array:

```
$('#submitBooking').on('click', function () {
           getDatesBetweenArriveAndDepart($('#inputArrive'), $('#inputDepart'));
           initCalendars();
        });
```

Inside of that click I need a function that sets a class to the arrive and depart day inside the datepicker.

Comment: share the code which you have tried (a fiddle would be great)

Comment: I added a part of my code I'm using. Everything works fine (could be I forgot to change a class/id or sth like that). I just need to know how to add a class inside of my datepicker or if it's possible to do that